# iOS / Xcode : Outpot posix_spawn() result to debug console

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there any way to output the result of posix_spawn() to the Xcode debug console with iOS ?

Example code:

```
int status = 0;
int success = 0;

pid_t pid;
char *argv[] = {
    "/usr/bin/pwd",
    NULL
};

success = posix_spawn(&pid, argv[0], NULL, NULL, argv, environ);
waitpid(pid, &status, WEXITED);

NSLog(@"Success: %i, Status: %i, PID: %d", success, status, pid);
//LOG RESULT-  Success: 1, Status: 0, PID: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always check the return value from a function like `posix_spawn()`. On iOS, it will always fail because you're not allowed to create subprocesses.

Even on OS X, if this is your real code, then it will fail because `posix_spawn()` does not search the `PATH` for an executable of the name you gave (`pwd`). That has to be the absolute or relative path to the executable. You could try `posix_spawnp()` as a variant which does search the `PATH`.

In the case where `posix_spawn[p]()` succeeds, the subprocess will, by default, inherit stdout and stderr, so its output should go to the console with no additional steps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes posix_spawn() returns 1 all the time which confused me because I forgot that 0 is in fact success.